# Understanding Route 53 query and health check fees

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I just registered a domain and set up a django project with it. I looked at my AWS bill, a lot of "international queries" and "non-aws health checks" happened within just a few days. And I have to pay for them.
Is this because there is some configuration that I didn't configure correctly? How can I reduce these?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much about the DNS-Queries but I wouldn't worry too long about $0.04. These are clients trying to resolve your DNS name using Route53 infrastructure.

The health check fee seems to indicate that your server is not running on AWS (or in a different Account), and you've configured R53 health checks that periodically ping that to see if it's available. This is something that you explicitly configured and can disable if you don't want it.

To quote from the [Route53 Pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/) (emphasis mine).

> An "AWS endpoint" is a **resource running within AWS** (e.g., an Amazon EC2 instance) **that is provisioned within the same AWS account as the health check or billed to the same account as the health check**. Calculated health checks and metric based health checks are billed as health checks of an AWS endpoint. [...]